# Lorentz force for a hole - in hole wavefunction

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

Consider a Lorentz force for a positve charge particle q, q>0 (not electrons, not holes, just general case), The lagrangian we can write down is
\begin{equation}
 L=\frac{m_0}{2}{\vec{v}}^2+q(\vec{A} \cdot \dot{\vec{{v}}}-\phi)=\frac{m_0}{2}\left(v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2\right)+q\left(v_x A_x+v_y A_y+v_z A_z\right)-q \phi
\end{equation}
Using Euler-Lagrange equation, we can get the Lorentz force for a postive charged particle with mass $m_0$,
\begin{equation}
 \vec{F} = q \vec{E}+q (\vec{v}\times\vec{B})
\end{equation}
Let us consider the electron case, we will have q > 0 to be replaced by -q for nagative charge.
\begin{equation}
\vec{a} = - \frac{q}{m_0} \vec{E} - \frac{q}{m_0} (\vec{v}\times\vec{B})
\end{equation}

**The question is**: How shoud we wrtie down the Lagrangian and Lorentz force for a hole in the sense of the hole wavefunction?

The idea of hole wavefunctions can be found fron https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.13725.pdf , and the discussion after equation 2.

**My thinking**: Holes are time reversed electrons, therefore we should just apply a time reversal on electron Lagrangian to get the hole Lagrangian. Moreover, we need to set the charge to be positve and mass to be negative, therefore we should have

\begin{equation}
L_H = - \frac{1}{2} m_0 \vec{v}^2 + q (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{v} - \phi)
\end{equation}
which will give us the Lorentz force
\begin{equation}
\vec{F} = \frac{q}{m_0} \vec{E} - \frac{q}{m_0} (\vec{v}\times\vec{B})
\end{equation}

Which looks dangerous since the hole and electrons will bend in a same way?

I have looked up all the post related holes, It appears to me that no one has talke about this before.

Comment: No, you should not be doing that. You should write down only for electrons, and then work out that the contribution of any complete band on current flow is zero. So, then, the contribution of any almost-completely-filled band is the completely filled band minus the holes' contribution, and then derive the holes' contribution from there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you elucidate a bit more?